# How to get the helper Mage_Review_Block_Helper?

Tags: magento, block, helper, review, mage

I tried since hours to get the method "getReviewsUrl()" from Mage_Review_Block_Helper to work inside my template.
But nothing works.

The simplest way I found is to use:

```
echo Mage::helper('review')->getReviewsUrl();
```

But when I call this from my product-template the site stop loading that is because when I call
Mage::helper('review');

It returns "**NULL**".

So this didn't work.

Next I tried it with

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('review/product_view',$this->getProduct());
```

But again no result. Isn't it possible to get the url for the reviews???

Answer (score 0):

Try the new operator;

```
$block = new Mage_Review_Block_Helper();
$block->setProduct($this->getProduct());
echo $block->getReviewsUrl();
```